# Attach External Bib File To my Tex Project

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
%Some Code Here
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{mybibfile.bib}
\end{document}
```

I read some posts about `bib` files and I recognized these codes but when do this, the `tex` file compiled but anything showed with refrence content!
In addition all of my files are in a unique file!

Comment: You need to run `bibtex` for example. Then compile twice.

Comment: @Sigur What is bibtex?

Comment: A program to read the `aux` file and create the biblio. You should have a button on the editor to run it.

Comment: Did it work? What editor are you using?

Comment: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: @Sigur Yeah Man, It Worked, I'm using MiKteK Compiler.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks a lot you help me in every question.lol :)